# Нужно переопределить сигнал clicked и передать в него аргументы

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, button, сигналы-слоты

Суть проста, не хочу городить два обработчика для кнопок у, которых по сути одно применение. Есть некоторое поле, слева и справа две мои кнопки. При нажатии на правую открывается модальное окно, при нажатие на левую тоже открывается модальное окно, разница лишь в тексте кнопок на модальном окне. Вот хотел бы просто передавать некоторый enum в кнопку, по которому потом и получал нужный текст в открывающемся модальном окне

Пишу свой собственный класс, наследующийся от QPushButton, нужно переопределить сигнал clicked и передать в него аргументы, как это сделать?

Comment: «*переопределить сигнал clicked*» — это самоцель или у этого есть какое-то практическое применение? если первое, то что именно ты подразумеваешь под «переопределить»?

Comment: @Fat-Zer Суть проста, не хочу городить два обработчика для кнопок у, которых по сути одно применение. Есть некоторое поле, слева и справа две мои кнопки. При нажатии на правую открывается модальное окно, при нажатие на левую тоже открывается модальное окно, разница лишь в тексте кнопок на модальном окне. Вот хотел бы просто передавать некоторый enum в кнопку,  по которому потом и получал нужный текст в открывающемся модальном окне

Comment: просто привяжи сигналы обычных кнопок к лямбдам и вызывай обработчик с нужными параметрами...

Comment: @Fat-Zer к лябдам, которые что делают, не очень логику понимаю.По сути лямбда, которая собирает нужные аргументы и вызывает другую функцию?

Comment: нуда, что-то типа: `connect(pbLeft, &QPushButton::clicked, [this](){this->createModalWindow("left");} );`... ну или можешь `std::bind` использовать вместо лямбд, если душа к чему-то более функциональному лежит...

Comment: да, кстати, есть ещё `QSignalMapper`, но со времён Qt5/C++11 им мало-кто пользуется...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно (и лучше) создать свой сигнал, со своим именем (чтобы потом не заниматься [приведением сигнала с нужным типом аргумента](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28465930/4711135)):

```
class MyButton : public QPushButton {
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    EnumType type;
public:
    MyButton(EnumType type, QWidget* parent =nullptr) : QPushButton(parent), type(type) {
        connect(this, &QPushButton::clicked, [&]() {
            emit myClicked(type);
        });
    }

signals:
    void myClicked(EnumType value);
}
```

И далее, где-то в коде:

```
connect(myButton /*указатель*/, &MyButton::myClicked, /*получатель сигнала с аргументом*/);
```